# ASP.NET MVC Get value from two column to one column

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, asp.net-mvc, excel

I have two columns from excel file:

> delivery_date1 - delivery_date2
>
> 2013-10-14   -    null
>
> null    -    2013-10-19

I want to update deliveries table using the two columns from the uploaded excel file but in the my table, I only have one column which is the delivery_date.

What I would like to have is like this (based on the excel data above):

> delivery_date
>
> 2013-10-14
>
> 2013-10-19

How can I do that using asp.net mvc?

Here's my code:

```
delivery_id = Convert.ToInt32(DB.db.Insert("dbo.deliveries", "delivery_id", new                                                                                                                    {
    delivery_date = delivery_date1,
    delivery_date = delivery_date2,
}));
```

I got an error like this:

> An anonymous type cannot have multiple properties with the same name.

Comment: is your example of expected behavior one record or two?

Comment: What do you mean _expected behavior_? @Zaphod

Comment: you have excel records which contains two parameters (2013-10-14 - null, a date an null) do you want these to map to a class with two date parameters (where one would be null) or one string that only shows dates that are not null. ie if the excel record was 2013-10-14 - 2013-10-15, do you want it as two date fields or one string that shows both dates?

Comment: What I want is that if the delivery_date1 is 2013-10-14 and delivery_date2 is null, delivery_date1 value should be added on the delivery_date, if null then don't add it. As well as in the second row -- delivery_date1 is null and delivery_date2 is 2013-10-19.. delivery_date2 value should be added on the delivery_date.

Comment: Ok, then I see you've been provided with the solution by musefan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which part of that error do you not understand? You cannot use the same property name twice!

I think this is what you want...

```
new 
{
    delivery_date = delivery_date1 == null ? delivery_date2 : delivery_date1
}
```

This will create a single property called `delivery_date` and will assign it the value of `delivery_date1`, or if `delivery_date1` is `null` then it will be assigned with the value of `delivery_date2`

Comment: Oh, I'm so sorry.. Anyway, I tried the code but it didn't worked. :( @musefan

Comment: @user3056503: What part didn't work? Do you have a new error?

Comment: Hi @musefan, it's now working! I forgot to add the delivery_date1 before null. Thank you! :)